# Adding a select input dynamically using CakePHP

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, select, cakephp-1.3

When a user adds an event, they need to be able to add Bands from the "bands" table to the event.  It's already all set up with the HABTM, and I have it working when I hard-code multiple select boxes to the page.

The problem is - I'd like to just have one select box, then an "add another band" button - which would add another select input with the list of bands - and so on - as many as they'd like.

I found this post:  [Add and remove form fields in Cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156374/add-and-remove-form-fields-in-cakephp)  which explains how to add a field dynamically... my issue is, the list of bands is huge, and changes regularly, so I can't imagine this working for me.

Any ideas on the best way to go about this?  - Adding a select input dynamically that's populated with a list of bands from my database?  Ajax maybe?  (I've no idea how to do ajax with cake yet)  Ajax seems ok, but do I really want to pull a list of bands every time the user clicks the "add a band" button?  Maybe that's ok?

Any help/direction is greatly appreciated.  Code example would be GREAT, but if nothing else, a nudge in the right direction would be very helpful.

Comment: Please stop writing tags in question titles.

Comment: @Tom - so I should make the title "adding a dynamically" ?

Comment: @Dave: "adding a select input dynamically". The fact that the question is about CakePHP is in the question tags.

Comment: @Tom - I didn't realize there were title police. :) My opinion is that "CakePHP" is a relevant portion of the title and will help to explain the nature of the question.  If you have the authority to change it, by all means go ahead, but I think you're incorrect. "Select" is also a tag, yet it's ok to leave that in?  What about "input"? - that's a tag too.  Heck even "dynamic" is a tag I believe.

Comment: @Dave: Stack Overflow is a community, and as such _everyone_ has the authority to change it. The vast majority [all?] of your 28 questions lead with "CakePHP - ", which is something tags were created in order to avoid, so that this information can be programmatically indexed, and presented in a consistent fashion. Tags and the title go hand-in-hand to provide a summary of what the question is about; the title is not on its own!

Comment: @Tom - i completely understand that - but without using tags in my title, it would literally be "adding a " - that's it.  So - I MUST use tags in my title to describe the question.  It just so happens, all of my questions have been about CakePHP.  Is there a list somewhere of tags that one SHOULD use in their titles vs ones that are off limits?  I would be glad to adhere to it.

Comment: @Dave: It seems that you have not understood me. I am sorry if I was not clear. :( Tags _plus_ the title go _hand in hand_. If the title doesn't have "CakePHP" in it, then that's **okay** because the tags have it.

Comment: @Tom - I believe understand you - you're complaining that I'm using "cakephp" in my title because it's a also tag.  What I don't understand is - in your opinion, how does one determine which tags are okay to use in the title, and which are ones that will get people like you to complain at people like me for using them?

Comment: @Dave: I generally avoid naming wider technologies/tools in titles. Specific components like "select" or "input" I would _not_ include as tags, and ought to be written part of a descriptive sentence in the title. A general rule is that if your technology is named on its own followed by a hyphen, and not as part of a sentence, it's probably in the wrong place!

Comment: @Dave, it's not just Tomalak's opinion, but general community opinion around here.  Pseudo-tags in the title are frowned upon.  There are *other* ways to communicate relevent information.  In this specific case, CakePHP *does* belong in the title to help disambiguate the question at first glance.  I have taken the liberty of updating the question title to ditch the pseudo-tag format but still keep it relevant and accurate.

Comment: After seeing the newly revised title, I like it's formatting better.  I don't really understand why it's that big of a difference, but I will refrain from using ______ - at the beginning of my posts, and attempt to include the tags within a more... readable sentence.

Comment: The more I think about this the more it makes less sense.  Am I really getting criticized for the incorrect placement of a word in my title? This seems like school children bickering that another child got the "wrong" kind of jelly in their PB&J sandwich.  Is there a reason for this other than "community opinion"?  When I read through titles, I would much rather see "ASP - How do I parse XML" than "How do I parse XML in ASP".  In the second example, I just wasted my time reading the sentence, when - if it were the first example, I could have immediately skipped it due to lack of ASP knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a single select input with an 'add band' button. When the user hits 'add band', catch the event with javascript, copy the selected band to a list (visually), and add the id to a hidden input (to be used when the form is submitted). jQuery/CakePHP example below.

```
<ul id='band_list'></ul>
<?php echo $form->create('Event', array('id'=>'event_form'));?>
<?php echo $form->input('band_ids', array('type'=>'hidden', 'id'=>'band_ids')); ?>
<?php echo $form->input('bands', array('type'=>'select', 'options'=>$bands, 'id'=>'bands_selector')); ?>
<button id='add_band'>Add Band</button>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var band_count = 0;
    $('#add_band').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('<li>' + $('#bands_selector option:selected').text() + '</li>').appendTo('#band_list');
        $('<input type="hidden" name="data[Band][Band]['+band_count.toString()+']" value="'+$("#bands_selector option:selected").val()+'">').appendTo('#event_form');
        band_count++;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ooh.. I like this idea... gonna try it out, thanks!  Will mark as answer if/when I get it to work, but - sounds like a great way to go!

Comment: the button literally just refreshes the page...  :(  I think I'm doing everything like what you have above - any thoughts?

Comment: Yah - even on a test page where I copy/paste that code, it's not working.. i verified i'm including the jquery.js (/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js)

Comment: got it working - using your concept, but changed code around - it won't let me select my own answer for 24 hours after posting, so feel free to change your answer accordingly, and let me know - I'd rather give you credit for the right answer since you led me to it.  Thanks again!  (will be posting answer shortly)

Comment: Hey thanks, and glad it put you on the right track. I had written it without testing, but have updated to your working version above.